# EF4 Code First: how to update specific fields only

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

How do I update only certain fields on an entity?

I have a User entity like so:

```
public class User
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string PasswordHash { get; set; }
    public bool IsDisabled { get; set; }
    public DateTime AccessExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public bool MustChangePassword { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastActivity { get; set; }
}
```

So if for example, I want to update the user entity, but do not want to change the user password, how do I do that?

Currently, I'm using the following code to update entities:

```
using (var _cnt = new STQContext())
{
   _cnt.Entry<Item>(item).State = System.Data.EntityState.Modified;
   _cnt.SaveChanges();
   return;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
using (var _cnt = new STQContext())
{
   _cnt.Users.Attach(user);
   _cnt.Entry<User>(user).Property(u => u.PasswordHash).IsModified = true;
   _cnt.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: I think he wanted the opposite... everything BUT the password

Comment: @Diego: Yes I see it now, but the principle is similar.

Comment: agreed. Does EF use what NH calls "dynamic-update" (build an UPDATE statement including only modified fields) by default?

Comment: @Diego: Interesting question. I will check it at home. I believe that it does for loaded entity but I'm not sure what happens with attached entity.

Comment: because, if it doesn't, the code would not work (i.e. it would update all the fields always)