# Entity Framework 4.1 RC (Code First) - Entity not updating over association

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first, entity-framework-4.1

What I'm trying to do is fairly simple.  I have two classes:

```
public class TownRecord
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ShortName { get; set; }
        public string FileName { get; set; }
        public string tags { get; set; }
        public virtual TownRecordType RecordType { get; set; }
        public DateTime? DateScanned { get; set; }
        public DateTime? RecordDate { get; set; }
        [StringLength(4000)]
        public string Comments { get; set; }
        public string UploadedBy { get; set; }
    }

    public class TownRecordType
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
            public string RecordType { get; set; }
            public virtual ICollection<TownRecord> TownRecords {get; set; }
        }
```

When I want to update the RecordType property on the TownRecord class, I find that the association fails to update.  No exception is thrown but the update is not performed:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Edit(int id, TownRecord tr, FormCollection collection)
 {
  TownRecordType newRecType = _ctx.TownRecordTypes.Find(Int32.Parse(collection["RecordType"]));
  tr.RecordType = newRecType;
  _ctx.Entry(tr).State = EntityState.Modified;
  _ctx.SaveChanges();
   return RedirectToAction("List");
  }
```

NOTE:  I removed my error handling for clarity...

I've seen a question similar to this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374404/ef4-code-first-how-to-update-specific-fields-only) but I'm not getting it.  This is probably a really foolish rookie mistake but I've StackOverflowing and Googling for several hours and getting nowhere.  Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ladislav, thanks.  Your solutionn worked.  I still needed to set the RecordType property (tr.RecordType = new RecType) because of some validation but it works.  Sorry I missed your other answer, but thanks very much for the guidance!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Entity Framework Code First - Why can't I update complex properties this way?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506116/entity-framework-code-first-why-cant-i-update-complex-properties-this-way)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's about a release candidate, and also an obsolete version of EF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't work because you are using independent association. Relation between `TownRecord` and `TownRecordType` is not part of town record's entry so changing state to modified doesn't say anything about state of relation. That is the real meaning of "independent" - it has its own entry but for unknown reason it is hard to get it in DbContext API (EF 4.1). Proposed way is using Foreign key association instead of independent association. To change your association to foreign key you must do this:

```
public class TownRecord
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    ...
    [ForeignKey("RecordType")]
    public int RecordTypeId { get; set; }
    public virtual TownRecordType RecordType { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

You will change your code to:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(int id, TownRecord tr, FormCollection collection)
{
    tr.RecordTypeId = Int32.Parse(collection["RecordType"]);
    _ctx.TownRecords.Attach(tr);
    _ctx.Entry(tr).State = EntityState.Modified;
    _ctx.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("List");
}
```

Actually the [question with the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506116/entity-framework-code-first-why-cant-i-update-complex-properties-this-way/5506262#5506262) was asked 2 hours before you asked the question. I also tried to provide solution which works with independent association but I don't like it. The problem is that for independent association you need to have attached `TownRecord` loaded its actual `TownRecordType` and replace it with new `TownRecordType`.

Comment: Still, it should work as the OP has it shouldn't it? I have a `User` class with a `public virtual IList<Suggestion> Suggestions {get;set;}` and a `Suggestion` class with a `public virtual User User {get;set;}`; it works without having to mark the FK relation explicitly, just by doing `user.Suggestions.Add(suggestion);`...