# MVC .NET How best to update model with file upload

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, code-first, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1

Using EF4 Codefirst RC and MVC .NET

I have a Strongly typed view I use to for my Insert/Update operations on my Model.
One of the field is a file/Image which is uploaded. I use the below code to do this.
Problem is when editing the form the 2nd time if the user does not select a file the File is set to NULL each time.

What different ways to people over come this.

I can

- Not store the image in the DB but on the file system (no possible as since this data is coming from an external API also)
- Change my View to have a separate form for editing images?

I have already read 
[EF4 Code First: how to update specific fields only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5374404/ef4-code-first-how-to-update-specific-fields-only)
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetentityframework/thread/81a0ee7d-bbe1-416c-9d84-7a30e04730fa/

and what I really would like is a way to Exclude a field from being updated? Is the only way I can do that with the code below? or is there a nicer way?

```
 public ActionResult Edit(CruiselineEditModel cruiseline, HttpPostedFileBase LogoData)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var cl = Mapper.Map<CruiselineEditModel, Cruiseline>(cruiseline);
            Cruiseline orgObj = _cl.GetById(cruiseline.Id);

            UpdateModel<Cruiseline>(orgObj, "", null, new string[] { "LogoData" });
            if (LogoData != null && LogoData.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                 byte[] imgBinaryData = new byte[LogoData.ContentLength];
                 int readresult = LogoData.InputStream.Read(imgBinaryData, 0, LogoData.ContentLength);
                 orgObj.LogoData = imgBinaryData;
            }
            _cl.Save();                  

        }
        return View(cruiseline);
    }
```

Comment: Ok  I just found the TryUpdateModel and UpdateModel methods. I think I am on the right track now

Comment: Can you post your CruiseLineEditModel.  I think your going to have to set LogoData manually after checking to see if you need to.  Update model is probably wiping out the entity value.

Comment: CruiselineEditModel has just a subset of properties that a cruieLine has, it does NOT have   byte[] LogoData

Comment: @Derek Beattie Just to clarify the code in my Question does now WORK.    I am just asking is this the correct way to do it? Is there a better way?

Comment: I see, I couldn't really see why that wouldn't work.  I think that looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for your help anyway you set my on the right path, also reading this site helpped http://geekswithblogs.net/michelotti/archive/2009/10/25/asp.net-mvc-view-model-patterns.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create an input ViewModel, then you can have separate annotations on the view model.  So, on the get, map entity to view model, on the post map view model to entity.  This will give you more flexibility in dealing with issues like this.

Comment: I tried doing this. But it still does not really help as sometimes I do want to map to the postedFile sometimes I do not. Unless I am not understanding you correctly.  I made a EditViewModel and used autoMapper like so var realObject = Mapper.Map<EditViewModel, Foo>(foo);  but when I save foo LogoData is still NULL and override my existing DB field.

Comment: What determines if you map to posted file or not?

Comment: This line if (LogoData != null && LogoData.ContentLength > 0).  i.e  If the user uploaded a file or not